# UwAmp : Apache HTTP server has stopped working

Tags: uwamp

I have a problem at start of UwAmp ; I get the message:

> Apache HTTP server has stopped working

So impossible to start Apache

A solution?

Thanks

I am running Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the "Visual C++ Redistributable x86 lib"

For PHP older version you need VC6 2005
For PHP 5.3 you need VC9 2008
For PHP 5.4+ you need VC11 2012
For PHP 7.x+ you need VC14 2015

Download links are on UwAmp download page in section Prerequisites.

Comment: I just installed Uwamp 3.1.0, when i open it Mysql server starts properly. but Apache server stops automatically every time. i searched a lot but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to directly start Apache by launching the executable `[UWAMP]\bin\apache\bin\httpd.exe`. An error message said me that the program didn't find the file "MSVCR110.dll".

I downloaded the file in http://www.telecharger-dll.fr/dll-msvcr110.dll.html and put it in the directory `[UWAMP]\bin\apache\bin\`.

Finally, I restarted UWAMp and Apache started.

Comment: Hello, @Tizel, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you confident that telecharger-dll is a safe site to download this library from? I'd be wary of downloading DLLs from third-party sources.